# Trigonometric equations with cosec

Tags: trigonometry

If $\frac{3\pi}{2}<t<2\pi$
  and $\\cost=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\\$
 , find the value of $\\cosec
 t+cos2t$

Comment: **tip:**
instead of writing
$$\frac{3\pi}{2}\lt t\lt 2\pi$$
try writing this instead
$$\frac{3}{4}(2\pi)\lt t\lt 2\pi$$
and interpret it as
$$\frac{3}{4}\text{ of a revolution}\lt t\lt \text{ one full revolution}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos2t=2\cos^2t-1$$

and in $\dfrac{3\pi}2<t<2\pi,\sin t<0\implies\sin t=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}$

and $\csc t=\dfrac1{\sin t}$

See also: [All Sin Tan Cos Rule](http://www.mathymind.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule-in-trigonometry/)